# What does this anti-crown button do?

Tags: clash-royale

I've tried pressing it and it doesn't appear to do anything. Does anyone know what it does? 
[image]
The update just came out today (at least for me it did).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Judging from [the patch notes](https://clashroyale.com/blog/release-notes/update-new-tournament-mode-cards-chests) and the [Rethinking Emotes blog post](https://clashroyale.com/blog/news/rethinking-emotes), it appears to be the button for muting the emotes of the other player.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tested on my friends devise on a friendly battle.